# PiP AVPlayerViewController issue iPhone

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayerviewcontroller, picture-in-picture

I'm studying AVFoundation and I want to create a thing similar to Whatsapp when see a youtube video for example that plays it in PiP mode.
For this reason I create viewcontroller like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface ViewController () <AVPictureInPictureControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4"];

    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    AVPlayer* playVideo = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    self.playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    self.playerViewController.player = playVideo;
    self.playerViewController.player.volume = 0;
    self.playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:self.playerViewController.view];
    self.playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    self.playerViewController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = YES;
    self.playerViewController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    [playVideo play];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

In the AppDelegate I did this:

```
NSError *errore = nil;
    AVAudioSession *sessioneAudio = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [sessioneAudio setActive:YES error:&errore];
    [sessioneAudio setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&errore];
```

And I enabled Audio,AirPlay and Picture in Picture background modes in project's Capabilities.

My problem is this:

If I run app on iPad device I see the PiP button and I can enabled PiP mode.
If I run app on iPhone device I don't see PiP button, but I don't understand why.

Comment: nobody can help me?

Comment: I think this is hide theme like CarPlay or NFC...no one result. Just customize library which can not use on ios 14

Answer (score -1):

I've implemented [PiPhone](https://github.com/ky1vstar/PiPhone) framework that enables PiP mode on iPhones. I think it can solve your problem.

Comment: PiPhone - this is your own library, has been writen on Swift. But he ask about Objective-C

Answer (score -1):

1. For the first in General - Capabilities choose Background Audio, AirPlay and PiP
2. Paste my code on Objective-C

   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
   self.AVPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
   self.layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_AVPlayer];

   [self.layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-100, self.view.frame.size.height-72)];
   [self.layer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResize];
   [self.view.layer addSublayer:_layer];

   [_AVPlayer play];
3. Check if Pip is support of current device

   -(void)setupSuport
   {
   if([AVPictureInPictureController isPictureInPictureSupported])
   {

   ```
      _AVPictureInPictureController =  [[AVPictureInPictureController alloc] initWithPlayerLayer:_layer];
        _AVPictureInPictureController.delegate = self;

    }
    else
    {
     // not supported PIP start button desable here
    }
   ```

   }
4. Action of PiP

-(IBAction)actionPIPStart:(UIButton*)sender
{

```
if (_AVPictureInPictureController.pictureInPictureActive) {
    [_AVPictureInPictureController stopPictureInPicture];
    NSLog(@"no PIP!");
}
else {
    [_AVPictureInPictureController startPictureInPicture];
    NSLog(@"PIP!");
}
```

}